# Executing SSIS package on SQL Server with a SQL Server authenticated user

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have deployed SSIS packages to SQL Server 2014. There I used a user created for the sole purpose to be a proxy for running the ssis packages over the SQL Server agent.

This worked quite well until today. A coworker made some changes that were not logged what exactly he did and now whenever I try to start the SSIS pacakges (manually in the SSIS catalog as this user has no permissions to see the sql server agent) I get the following error message:

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server
>   Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows
>   Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27123)

Now my question here is: what can I do to be able to run these packages again with that user.

The credentials themselves point to a Windows domain user

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the OLE DB connection is using Windows Authentication vs SQL Server Authentication? Even if the user is a domain user, credentials need to be passed when using SQL Server Authentication anyway. They also may have a policy different from Windows (expiration differences, etc.) You could also check the Integrated Security type, making sure that hasn't changed.

Comment: The SSIS catalog keeps history - just right click the project name, and look at versions.  You can set a particular version as active, download that to your workstation.  Do this twice with different names, and you have the ability to determine what changes your co-worker made.

Comment: I have found SSIS to be a little kludgy when running packages by themselves.  I have always created SQL Agent jobs that run my packages with the configurations I want.

Comment: @RajMore that is exactly what I'm doing there. The sql agent jobs are running the ssis packages (and use a proxy as the account running the sql server agent doesnt have access to the ssis packages themselves but the proxy has). And that proxy account is the account where the error occurs